# How to find angle made by the image with the front parallel view?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, perspective

I am working on a problem in order to warp the perspective of images to get a front-parallel view. Non-front-parallel plane of the image is rotated by angle alpha with respect to x-axis and by angle beta with respect to y-axis, assuming optical axis of camera as z-axis. Can we estimate alpha and beta? If so how? What is the mathematical procedure one should follow in order to find these angles? Are there any library functions for this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

circles = np.zeros((4,2),np.int)
counter = 0

def mousePoints(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global counter
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        circles[counter] = x,y
        counter = counter + 1
        print(circles)

img = cv2.imread("DSC_0273.JPG")

img = cv2.resize(img,(1500,1000))
q = 0
while True:

    if counter == 4:
        q = q+1

        height1,width1 = 1080,1920
        pts1 = np.float32([circles[0],circles[1],circles[2],circles[3]])
        width = np.sqrt((circles[1][0] - circles[0][0])**2 + (circles[1][1] - circles[0][1])**2)
        height =  np.sqrt((circles[2][1] - circles[0][1])**2 + (circles[2][0] - circles[0][0])**2)
        width = int(np.round(width))
        height = int(np.round(height))
        x1,y1 = circles[0]
    
        pts2 = np.float32([[x1,y1],[(x1+width),y1],[(x1+width),(y1+height)],[x1,(y1+height)]])
        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

        if q == 1:
            print(matrix.shape)
            print(matrix)
        imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img,matrix,(width1,height1))
        cv2.imshow("Output Image ", imgOutput)


for x in range (0,4):
    cv2.circle(img,(circles[x][0],circles[x][1]),3,(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)

cv2.imshow("Original Image ", img)
cv2.setMouseCallback("Original Image ", mousePoints)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Can you detect four points forming an axis-aligned rectangle on the non-parallel view ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have added the code I am using to warp the perspective for your reference.
I have a few images. I run this code. It allows me to click at any 4 points(in the order, top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left). Then my code finds the transform matrix using cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(). I myself give the points. I don't know how to detect 4 points on an axis aligned to the non-parallel view.

Comment: If you can only click on points in the perspective view, all this is of no use. You need pairs of corresponding points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not clearly understand what u meant there.
I choose 4 points on the original image so that the area enclosed within those 4 points are mapped to a rectangle.
The first point I give is mapped to the same pixel location, as in the original image. The other 3 points get moved so that finally, the 4 mapped points form a rectangle. 
The transformation matrix for this is found and applied to the whole image.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have been waiting for your reply. Can you clarify on what you meant there

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the four points in both spaces ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I do. I store the coordinates of the points I click on, and the points to which I map to.

Comment: Then write the homographic equations, which involve 8 unknown parameters, and write the system of 8 equations obtained from the coordinate pairs. Fortunately, the equations can be linearized. The next step is to obtain the rotation matrix by establishing the relation between the 3D to 2D projection equations and the homography.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hey I am not able to exactly understand your answer. Can you explain a bit more? If possible can u suggest some sources as well, which can help in understanding concepts related to this.

Comment: Lookup "homographic transformation". Then write the system of 8 equations in 8 unknowns.